# How do I sniff website url in a https packet request in wireshark?

Tags: https, wireshark, packet-sniffers

I am able to sniff http packets and extract the website from there. But I am unable to sniff websites that use https. I only want the website to know what websites people are accessing. I have access to the router thus I can sniff all packets in the network. Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's impossible to get full url from HTTPS connection, since it's encrypted, but getting domain name is possible. In order to visit any website, PC must know its IP address, so it performs DNS lookup using site domain name, unless IP address is cached or stored locally in hosts file.

So you can apply `dns` display filter and get domain names requested by PC thus getting list of domains for visited sites. Wireshark should be able to automatically show domain name instead of IP addresses for traces with DNS traffic, check [resolve network addresses option](https://ask.wireshark.org/questions/37680/can-wireshark-automatically-resolve-the-ip-address-into-host-names).

If DNS packets aren't presented, you can try getting domain name of site by using its address in [reverse DNS lookup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_DNS_lookup) request.

Comment: So instead of displaying IP address destination, wireshark can display the domain name? For example, in the website www.example.com/test, it will be able to show www.example.com only and not /test? Am I right?

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. One more thing btw, is it really impossible to get /test if www.example.com uses https? Or is there a way to figure that out?

Comment: /test is a part of HTTP request (e.g. client sends "GET /test" within HTTP packet to get this page). HTTPS means secure HTTP, so HTTP content is encrypted. One of the main goals of encryption is to hide content from anyone not involved into communication. So only client and server knows session keys for encryption, if none of them is you, you can't decrypt content.